# How To Get Stored Database Image In Dropdown List Box?

Tags: magento-1.9, image

How To Fetch Stored Database Image In Dropdown List Box?
And If Specific Image Are Select Then This Image Are Also Show At Frontend.

This Is My COde..
**app\code\local\Hs\Simplebanner\Block\Adminhtml\Simplebanner\Edit\Tab\Form.php**

```
$fieldset->addField('select', 'select', array(
'label'     => Mage::helper('simplebanner')->__('Select Your Image'),
'required'  => true,
'name'      => 'select',
));
```

**app\code\local\Hs\Simplebanner\Block\Adminhtml\Simplebanner\Grid.php**

```
$this->addColumn('select', array(
'header'    => Mage::helper('simplebanner')->__('Select Your Image'),
'align'     => 'left',
'width'     => '80px',
'index'     => 'status',
'type'      => 'options',       
'options'   => array(           
),
));
```

Comment: provide some info sample website code or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for showing the option in form but you can't show the image in select

```
  $imagescollection = Mage::getSingleton('modulname/model')->getCollection();
           $imgelist=array();
           $imgelist[] = array (
                     'value' => '', 'label' => Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Select image')
                 );
           foreach ($imagescollection as $image) {
               $imgelist[] = array (
                     'value' => $image->getId(), 'label' => $image->getImage()
                 );
             }


     $fieldset->addField('select', 'select', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('simplebanner')->__('Select Your Image'),
        'required'  => true,
        'name'      => 'select',
        'values'    => $imgelist,

      ));
```

for grid i am not sure what you are trying here..